# By hover, trigger another element's hover

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseenter

I want to trigger another element's hover by hovering an element like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.quarter h3').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).next().trigger('mouseenter');
    });
});
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="quarter grow">
    <a href="#">
        <h3><span>titel 1</span></h3>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/230/people/1" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KkYGC/

Comment: You can't, as far as I know, use JavaScript to trigger the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class. You'd need to use jQuery to add/remove a class on `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` instead I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood your problem correctly you could just change

```
.grow img:hover {
```

to

```
.grow:hover img {
```

Comment: I think we've understood the question the same way because I think that should do it.